# Remove and add Shapes in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, header, footer, shapes

I want to remove and add an existing Shape in Word (Header and Footer) with a Button

But i can't select the shape to change the visible property.

How can I do this? I can't figure out the name of the shape in Word

Thanks for your Help!

```
Sub LogoChangeVisible()
'
' Removes and adds the logo from Header and Footer
'
'
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader

Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes("Picture from Header").Select

If Selection.ShapeRange.Visible = msoTrue Then
Selection.ShapeRange.Visible = msoFalse
Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes("Picture from Footer").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Visible = msoFalse

ElseIf Selection.ShapeRange.Visible = msoFalse Then
Selection.ShapeRange.Visible = msoTrue
Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes("Picture from Footer").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Visible = msoTrue
End If

ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add something like this:

```
For Each s In Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes
    Debug.Print s.Name
Next
```

Then you'll get the names in your debug window. Another approach is to ignore the names and go by numbers instead:

```
Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes(1)...
```

Comment: It didn't find any shapes. Does it count as a shape if its a jpg picture?

Comment: Yes, it does count as a shape, but it can be an inline shape as well. Try this:  


    Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InlineShapes.Count